# React warnings regarding the component rendering

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the child component inside the parent component. Like below,

```
class Parent extends Component() {
  getContent() {
    let arr = [{name: 'abc'},{name: 'bcd'},{name: 'cde'}];
    return arr.map(data => <Child name={data.name}/>)
  }  

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.getContent()}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Above code gives warning

> Each child in an array should have a unique "key" prop. Check the
>   render method of TableComponent

I don't want the answer like **use the unique key as props in child component**. Instead please clarify the point why react gives such type of warning what will be the drawback if I don't use the unique key here. Please provide the example of this causes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Comment: See in particular [the second most-upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43892905/216074) for an in-depth explanation on what the `key` is used for.

Answer (score 0):

Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity